# Unable to display image in listview item

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview

I am trying to get the image from a url and display it into a listview item.
The url is take from a mysql database via a php.

Currently i am not able to get the image to display in my listview item.

The process i am using is to first download the image and cache it then display it on the listview item. ( base on what i have search on the web, we can take a direct url and display it into the listview item).

any advise or coding will be a great.

Below is the code i am using and facing the problem.

```
public void GetProduct () {

        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Fetching Data", "Wait...", false, false);
            }            
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                JSON_STRING = s;
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list2= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
                    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
                    Log.d("JSON", Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
                        String TITLE = jo.getString(Config.TAG_TITLE);
                        String BRAND = jo.getString(Config.TAG_BRAND);
                        String ITEMTYPE = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ITEMTYPE);
                        String BOOSTERTYPE = jo.getString(Config.TAG_BOOSTERTYPE);
                        String PRICE = jo.getString(Config.TAG_PRICE);
                        String IMGURL = jo.getString(Config.TAG_IMGURL);
                        String QTYINSTOCK = jo.getString(Config.TAG_QTYINSTOCK);
                        String QTYPENDING = jo.getString(Config.TAG_QTYPENDING);

                        HashMap<String, String> event = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        event.put(Config.TAG_ID, id);
                        event.put(Config.TAG_TITLE, TITLE);
                        event.put(Config.TAG_BRAND, BRAND);
                        event.put(Config.TAG_ITEMTYPE, ITEMTYPE);
                        event.put(Config.TAG_PRICE, PRICE);
                        event.put(Config.TAG_IMGURL, IMGURL);
                        event.put(Config.TAG_QTYINSTOCK, QTYINSTOCK);
                        event.put(Config.TAG_QTYPENDING, QTYPENDING);

//the code i added for picasso
                         ImageView img = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.iv_flag);
                    String imgUrl = (String)event.get(Config.TAG_IMGURL);
                    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imgUrl).into(img);
                            list2.add(event);
                            ListAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(
                                            getActivity().getBaseContext(), list2, R.layout.productitem,
                                            new String[]{Config.TAG_TITLE, Config.TAG_PRICE, Config.TAG_BRAND, Config.TAG_ITEMTYPE, Config.TAG_QTYINSTOCK, "flag"},
                                            new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3, R.id.text4, R.id.text5, R.id.iv_flag});
                            ProductListing.setAdapter(adapter);
                            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>)adapter.getItem(i);
                            String imgUrl = (String)event.get(Config.TAG_IMGURL);
                            ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();
                            HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            hm.put("flag_path", imgUrl);
                            hm.put("position",i);
                            imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data [" + e.getMessage() + "] " + jsonObject);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();                
                    String s = rh.sendGetRequest("the url for my php file");
                    return s;
                }
            }
            final GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
            gj.execute();
        }
        /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
        private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{
            @Override
            protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {
                InputStream iStream=null;
                String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
                Log.d("url1", imgUrl);
                int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");
                URL url;
                try {
                    url = new URL(imgUrl);
                    // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    // Connecting to url
                    urlConnection.connect();
                    // Reading data from url
                    iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    // Getting Caching directory
                    File cacheDirectory = getActivity().getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
                    // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
                    File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");
                    // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                    FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
                    // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);
                    // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);
                    // Flush the FileOutputStream
                    fOutStream.flush();
                    //Close the FileOutputStream
                    fOutStream.close();
                    // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
                    HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                    hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());
                    // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                    hmBitmap.put("position",position);
                    // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
                    return hmBitmap;

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
                // Getting the path to the downloaded image
                String path = (String) result.get("flag");
                // Getting the position of the downloaded image
                int position = (Integer) result.get("position");
                // Getting adapter of the listview
                SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter)ProductListing.getAdapter();
                // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);
                // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
                hm.put("flag",path);
                // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

The LogCat:

```
06-11 19:16:21.621 21935-22767/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/url1: http://www.genesisfrontier.com/cfs/files/images/ib53ZANJkNPJ2cQCS/BFEH_EB2.png
06-11 19:16:21.621 21935-22767/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-11 19:16:21.631 21935-22767/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
06-11 19:16:21.731 21935-21935/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-11 19:16:21.731 21935-21935/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:
```

below is the logcat for picasso

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 1289
                                                                            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
                                                                                at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
                                                                                at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
                                                                                at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.FindPeopleFragment$1GetJSON.onPostExecute(FindPeopleFragment.java:147)
                                                                                at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.FindPeopleFragment$1GetJSON.onPostExecute(FindPeopleFragment.java:91)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso lib to download image from Url it will automatically download image from url. To use Picasso library add this in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and then do like this

```
String imgUrl = (String)event.get(Config.TAG_IMGURL);
Picasso.with(context).load(imgUrl).into("your imageview");
```

Comment: i have add the code in as pre below but getting error on the Picasso line.
 ImageView img = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.iv_flag);
 String imgUrl = (String)event.get(Config.TAG_IMGURL);
 Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imgUrl).into(img);

is this correct? the image is in the listview item

Comment: what error you are getting and where you can set your image in imageview in your adapter?

Comment: do you mean the layout where the imageview is for the image from URL?

Comment: No.I am talking about Javafile that where you can initialize your imageView

Comment: if i have added it wrongly where should i place it?

Comment: Please Debug your code add check that your image id is null, you pass into picasso. You can initialize your image in getView() method and then pass it here else you can visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985668/picasso-illegalargumentexception

Comment: I think i understand it abit. it tell me that it cant find the imageview hence it feedback a null right?

Comment: where is your getView() method or else where place you call GetProduct() method code